# Progress Indicator In a Table Cell

Tags: javafx-8

I have a table column which i added through Scene Builder, and with java code i made it editable like so

```
colSellingPrice.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Sale, Float>forTableColumn(new FloatStringConverter()));
```

The problem is during updating the value in this tablecell, alot of calculations and many insertion and fetching is made which takes time to complete. Though i decided to put the update logic in a `Task`, i would also like to display a progress indicator in the tablecell UI while the logic is happenning.

This is what i have so far

```
colSellingPrice.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Sale, Float>>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Sale, Float> t) {
            Task task = new Task<Void>(){
                private SaleTransaction st;
                @Override
                protected Void call() throws Exception {
                    Sale s = t.getRowValue();
                    // Logic, logic , logic

                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void succeeded() {
                    System.out.println("Price Updated.");
                }
            };
            executor.submit(task);
        }
    });
```

Comment: OT: you can simplify that to `Sale s = t.getRowValue();`. For the actual question, you probably need to place some properties in the row value (i.e. the `Sale` class) that represent updating state. Otherwise you'll have a lot of trouble keeping the cell state correct if the cell is reused while an update is in progress.

Comment: @James_D, how will the property help keeping cell state correct

Comment: Because the cell always knows its current item, so it can always observe the appropriate state if you include it there.

Comment: @James_D, Sorry i have no idea on how to implement what you are suggesting. Some pseudo-code will be helpfull